# Where did the apes find another Icarus spaceship to return to Earth?

Tags: science, planet-of-the-apes

Where did the apes find another Icarus spaceship to return to earth? How did they have the knowledge to pilot it?

Comment: ["Some time later, Dr. Milo recovered the wreckage of the ship and somehow restored it to working order, taking off moments before the Earth's destruction."](http://planetoftheapes.wikia.com/wiki/Icarus_/_Liberty_1)

Comment: You might want to precise a bit your question. 
For example it is not clear which movie/franchise you are talking about, even though it's probably "Escape from the Planet of the Apes"

Answer (score 4):

In the movie "Escape from the Planet of the Apes" (1971), three apes — Cornelius (Roddy McDowall), Zira (Kim Hunter), and Dr. Milo (Sal Mineo) — escape the destruction of Earth by salvaging and repairing Taylor's spaceship (i.e. the spaceship Icarus, as seen in the original 1968 film).

As to how they knew how to pilot it, the film does not say (such events occur off-screen). But, as these were highly intelligent apes, they presumably "worked it out". They pilot it through the shock wave of Earth's destruction, and journey through a time warp.

Answer (score 2):

### In-universe:

About twenty minutes into the film, *Escape from the Planet of the Apes*, the US President gives a briefing to various officials in which he informs them that the spacecraft Cornelius, Zira and Dr. Milo arrived in was the same one commanded by Taylor in the first film.

> THE PRESIDENT: Yesterday, a U.S. spacecraft splashed down off the Southern California coast. It was one of two that have been missing in space for over two years now. To be exact, **the one commanded by Colonel Taylor.**
>
> <sub>*Escape from the Planet of the Apes* (1971)</sub>

A few minutes later into the runtime, during a Presidential Commission of Enquiry, Cornelius gave Dr. Milo -- whom he described as a "genius well in advance of his time" -- credit for salvaging the spacecraft and studying it sufficiently to be able to navigate it.

> CORNELIUS: **Dr. Milo was a genius well in advance of his time. When the spacecraft first landed on our seaboard, it was Dr. Milo who salvaged it. He studied it and, uh, half understood it.**
>
> UNNAMED COMMISSION MEMBER #1: Half? Was half enough?
>
> CORNELIUS: **It was enough for us to escape when war became inevitable.**
>
> [...]
>
> ARMY OFFICER: Who won the war?
>
> CORNELIUS: I don't know. Chimpanzees are pacifists. We stayed at home.
>
> UNNAMED COMMISSION MEMBER #2: But **you left before the war had ended.**
>
> ARMY OFFICER: **In a spaceship.**
>
> NAVAL OFFICER: **Which Dr. Milo learned to navigate.**
>
> CORNELIUS: **Correct.**
>
> <sub>*Escape from the Planet of the Apes* (1971)</sub>

It does seem like a stretch that the apes could have pulled this off, but I gather the idea is that Dr. Milo was a uniquely gifted individual, whose technological prowess far exceeded that of his peers.

---

### Behind the scenes:

It's also worth noting that the filmmakers basically wrote themselves into a corner with the ending of the second film, *Beneath the Planet of the Apes*, in which all life on Earth was ended by the detonation of an experimental nuclear bomb.

> NARRATOR: In one of the countless billions of galaxies in the universe lies a medium-sized star. And one of its satellites, a green and insignificant planet, is now dead.
>
> <sub>*Beneath the Planet of the Apes* (1970)</sub>

This ending was suggested by Charlton Heston, because he didn't want to do a third Apes film, and didn't really even want to be in the second one, which is why James Franciscus was cast as the lead. Heston only agreed to be in the second film at all on the conditions that his role would be small and that his character would be killed off.

> CHARLTON HESTON: Dick Zanuck called me. He said "Chuck, we have to do a sequel, you know. This film is enormous." **I said "I don't want to do a sequel. That's like the Andy Hardy series." And he said "Chuck, I can't make the sequel if you're not in it." And I said "Well, you got me, Richard, because we couldn't have made this film if you hadn't given it a go. So how about if I'm in the sequel but I get killed in the opening scene,** and you pay me whatever you want and we'll give it to a school or something?" He said "OK, that's fine, that's a deal." And then, as the script developed, he called and said "Chuck, **how about if we have you disappear in the first scene and then you're killed in the last scene?" And I said "Yeah, I guess. OK, fine. What the heck."**
>
> <sub>*Behind the Planet of the Apes* (1998)</sub>

Apparently, killing Taylor off wasn't definitive enough for Heston; he didn't want there to be be any more sequels at all. So he proposed that the second film should end with the Earth itself being blown up by an atom bomb.

> RODDY MCDOWALL: **The ending was suggested by Heston himself, who was very wary of any more ape sequels.**
>
> CHARLTON HESTON: **I said "How about if I set off this atom bomb and blow up the whole Earth?" And they said "That's very good." And I thought "That's the end of the sequels."**
>
> <sub>*Behind the Planet of the Apes* (1998)</sub>

Heston likely got the ending he wanted in part because the producers weren't planning on making a third film at the time. They certainly had no plans to make a second film whilst the first was in production.

> MORT ABRAHAMS: Stan Huff, head of production, says "You gotta do a sequel." I said "Stan, there's no way we can do a sequel. There's no place to go. I don't wanna to do a thing on Mars." He said "You have to find a way." I had never thought of a sequel.
>
> RICHARD ZANUCK: At the time of *Planet of the Apes*, no one was talking sequels very much, or at all. For 20th Century Fox, at that period of time, this started the notion of recapturing the success of the first.
>
> <sub>*Behind the Planet of the Apes* (1998)</sub>

The second film ended up making a pretty healthy profit at the box office though, which apparently led to a change of heart. The screenwriter of the second film, Paul Dehn, was effectively asked to pull a rabbit out of a hat, and conjure up a way to move the plot forward out of an ending that was intentionally designed by Charlton Heston to frustrate that.

> RODDY MCDOWALL: With *Beneath the Planet of the Apes*, the ape saga now seemed to have reached a logical conclusion. The prophecies of the apes' sacred scrolls had come true. The beast man had wielded his final weapon of destruction. But, **just four months after the film's release, screenwriter Paul Dehn received a telegram from Arthur Jacobs. "Apes exist. Sequel required." Dehn was now faced with a seemingly insurmountable task. How do you carry on after you've blown up the world?** While puzzling over the problem of how to create a third Apes adventure, Paul Dehn thought of astronaut Taylor's spaceship from the first film. It gave him an idea. What if, just prior to the world's destruction in *Beneath the Planet of the Apes*, the abandoned craft had somehow been salvaged and repaired? Now the story could move forward by bringing the apes back in time. And, through the magic of science fiction, that's exactly what happened in *Escape from the Planet of the Apes*.
>
> <sub>*Behind the Planet of the Apes* (1998)</sub>

As I suggested above, the solution Dehn came up with was certainly a stretch, but considering the ending of the second film, it's hard to see how he could've moved the plot forward in a way that wouldn't have required considerable suspension of disbelief on the audience's part.

Answer (score 0):

The internal configuration of the ship that Milo piloted was different from Taylor's sleeper ship interior with the cryo tubes. It was probably similar to Brent's ship. Maybe Milo found Brent's ship and going over records and such found onboard Milo discovered where ANSA's vehicle assembly and berthing hangar was. And upon finding it he discovered an intact ship that could be made launch ready.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence for this theory?  Answers should be supported with details revealed by the works or their creators.

Answer (score -3):

Charlton Heston's (Taylor) Icarus sunk at the cross of Father's Canyon lake.
James Francesco's ship did not turn up to the battle beneath the planet of the apes.
The ship that returned to Earth was way before the mentioned movie above.